# android camera2 api MediaRecorder stop() error

Tags: android, api, video-capture, camera2

I am very new in android and I am trying to create a simple video recorder app using android camera2 api. By following a tutorial on youtube I managed to preview the camera in a TextureView and start capturing with MediaRecorder, but I am having trouble on stopping the recorder and saving the video to my device storage.

This error appears on MediaRecorder.stop()

> W/Adreno-EGLSUB: : dequeue native buffer fail: No such device, buffer=0x0, handle=0x0
>   W/Adreno-EGL: : EGL_BAD_SURFACE
>   E/CameraDeviceGLThread-0: Received exception on GL render thread: 
>                             java.lang.IllegalStateException: swapBuffers: EGL error: 0x300d
>                                 at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.SurfaceTextureRenderer.checkEglError(SurfaceTextureRenderer.java:544)
>                                 at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.SurfaceTextureRenderer.swapBuffers(SurfaceTextureRenderer.java:537)
>                                 at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.SurfaceTextureRenderer.drawIntoSurfaces(SurfaceTextureRenderer.java:741)
>                                 at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.GLThreadManager$1.handleMessage(GLThreadManager.java:105)
>                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                 at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
>   I/CameraDeviceState: Legacy camera service transitioning to state ERROR

I am using an Android 6.0 api23 device to run the app.

Thanks

**EDIT**:
Here is the stopRecording function.

```
                try{
                    previewSession.stopRepeating();
                    previewSession.abortCaptures();
                }catch(CameraAccessException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                recorder.stop();
                recorder.reset();
                isRecording = false;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Recording Stopped",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

...based on @NewOne's answer, I included the try catch before the recorder.stop() then I have a new error

> --------- beginning of crash E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.tingker.daryl.camera2, PID: 9014
>                     Theme: themes:{default=overlay:com.cyngn.hexo, iconPack:com.cyngn.hexo, fontPkg:com.cyngn.hexo,
>   com.android.systemui=overlay:com.cyngn.hexo,
>   com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:com.cyngn.hexo}
>                     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session has been closed; further changes are illegal.
>                         at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.checkNotClosed(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:606)
>                         at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.stopRepeating(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:272)
>                         at com.tingker.daryl.camera2.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:121)
>                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
>                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21158)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, currently, what is there in your stop recording method. If you could share, may be I can help better. Anyways make sure you have the below lines of code before you call the stop method.

```
private void stopRecording()) {

        .....

        try {
            preview.stopRepeating();
            preview.abortCaptures();
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try{
           mediaRecorder.stop();
        }catch(RuntimeException e){
           //handle the exception
        }
        mediaRecorder.reset();

        ......
    }
```

Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#stop%28%29). You may catch the exception if you are stopping the recorder immediately after starting it.

Comment: Are you calling stop method immediately after starting the recorder? This is from android developer website: Note that a RuntimeException is intentionally thrown to the application, if no valid audio/video data has been received when stop() is called. This happens if stop() is called immediately after start(). The failure lets the application take action accordingly to clean up the output file (delete the output file, for instance), since the output file is not properly constructed when this happens. Please see my edited answer

Comment: hey thanks, I found out that there were two CameraCaptureSession that were set in my code - on the setup of camera preview and the other one on starting the media recorder. The one I used on the stopRecording() was the session of the camera preview which caused the new error.
..Now I tried to use the session set when starting the media recorder then it all went okay and problem solved.

Thanks man, I marked your answer as the correct one.

Comment: Happy to know that your problem has been fixed.

Comment: @Handsum you said `the session set when starting the media recorder` on above comment. I wish could please can explain bit more.